# Linearly Independent Vectors and Colinearity (Proof Verification)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm practicing my proof-writing and was hoping you could let me know if this proof looks good. I would like to know if the proof is incorrect, if there are parts that are overly wordy/complicated, or if I'm missing some element of a proof that is helpful to see, if not strictly necessary.

**The Prompt (from [here](https://are.berkeley.edu/courses/ARE211/currentYear/problem_sets/psLinAlgebra1Qu.pdf)):**

Two nonzero vectors are linearly independent if and only if they are not colinear (or
proportional, i.e. for two vectors (u,v), there exists λ ∈ R such that u = λ.v)

**My Proof:**

*Sufficiency:* Suppose two nonzero vectors v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub> are linearly independent, but let them be colinear so that v<sub>1</sub> = λv<sub>2</sub>. Then:

t<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + t<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub> = 0

λt<sub>1</sub>v<sub>2</sub> + t<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub> = 0

v<sub>2</sub>(λt<sub>1</sub> + t<sub>2</sub>) = 0

This implies that λt<sub>1</sub> = -t<sub>2</sub> even for nonzero values of t<sub>1</sub> and t<sub>2</sub>, which contradicts the fact that v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub> are linearly independent, so v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub> must not be colinear.

*Necessity:* We prove the necessary condition by the contrapositive. Suppose v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub> are not linearly independent, so that there is some nonzero t ∈ R<sup>2</sup> such that t<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + t<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>=0. Then t<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> = -t<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub> so v<sub>1</sub> = -(t<sub>2</sub>/t<sub>1</sub>)v<sub>2</sub> so v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub> are proportional (by the scalar -t<sub>2</sub>/t<sub>1</sub>) and colinear. Since v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub> not being linearly independent implies them being colinear, if they are not colinear then they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is basically fine apart from the following points.

You shouldn't have `$=0$' in each line in your chain of equations in the proof of sufficiency, and there is the possibility of one of the vectors being zero to be (briefly) considered. What I would suggest is something like this.

> Suppose that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent but that they are collinear.
>   If $v_1$ or $v_2$ are equal to zero then $v_1$ and $v_2$ cannot be linearly independent, so suppose that $v_1,v_2\neq 0$. Since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are collinear we have $v_1=\lambda v_2$ for some $\lambda\neq 0$. Now for any $t_1,t_2\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
>
> $\begin{array}{ll} & t_1v_1+ t_2v_2\\
> = & \lambda t_1v_2 + t_2v_2\\
> = & v_2(\lambda t_1 + t_2)\end{array}$
>
> But if $t_1\neq 0$ and $t_2=-\lambda t_1$ we get $v_2(\lambda t_1 + t_2)=0$, which contradicts the fact that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent.
>   Therefore $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not collinear.

Of course it's important to note that at least one of $t_1,t_2$ is non-zero (as you had in your own proof) to make sure you have a contradiction.

In your proof of necessity you have $t$ instead of $t_1$ and $t_2$. I would suggest something like `... so there are $t_1,t_2\in\mathbb{R}$, not both zero, such that $t_1v_1+t_2v_2=0$. Suppose that $t_1\neq 0$ (the case where $t_2\neq 0$ is similar). Then $t_1v_1=-t_2v_2$...'

Finally, the word is usually spelled *collinear*. Apart from that it's a fine proof.